# Trouble programming using objects for Battleship

Tags: java

I have to create a Battleship program with the player as the object and then the Array Boards being part of the fields. I have a minor error somewhere in the code which I can't seem to figure what it is exactly. I have a main method and a class where my methods are defined. I get an error saying it can't find the symbol at "a.setBoard()" and "b.setBoard()"

```
public class Player_p2 implements Player{

//fields
char [][] Board1 = new char [11][10]; 
char [][] Board2 = new char[11][10]; 


//methods


public void setBoard () {
this.Board1 = Board1;
this.Board2 = Board2;


    int row = Board1.length;
    int col = Board1[0].length;
    char a = '~';

    for (int k = 1; k < row; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < col; l++) {
            Board1[k][l] = a;
        }
    }

    int row1 = Board1.length;
    int col1 = Board1[0].length;
    char b = '~';

    for (int m = 1; m < row1; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < col1; n++) {
            Board1[m][n] = b;
        }
    }

    Board1[0][0] = '0';
    Board1[0][1] = '1';
    Board1[0][2] = '2';
    Board1[0][3] = '3';
    Board1[0][4] = '4';
    Board1[0][5] = '5';
    Board1[0][6] = '6';
    Board1[0][7] = '7';
    Board1[0][8] = '8';
    Board1[0][9] = '9';

    Board2[0][0] = '0';
    Board2[0][1] = '1';
    Board2[0][2] = '2';
    Board2[0][3] = '3';
    Board2[0][4] = '4';
    Board2[0][5] = '5';
    Board2[0][6] = '6';
    Board2[0][7] = '7';
    Board2[0][8] = '8';
    Board2[0][9] = '9';

}

public void printBoard() {
    this.Board2 = Board2;

    int row = Board2.length;
    int col = Board2[0].length;

        for (int k = 0; k < row; k++) {
        System.out.print(k + " ");
            for (int l = 0; l < col; l++) {
                System.out.print(Board2[k][l] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    } 
}

}

public class Battleship {


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Player a = new Player_p2();
    Player b = new Player_p2();


    //initializes the empty boards
    a.setBoard();
    b.setBoard();
    a.printBoard();
    b.printBoard();



}
}

public interface Player{

public void printBoard();
}
```

Comment: We will always want the full error text, including line numbers.

Comment: I'm surprised that the compiler doesn't complain about assigning a Player_p2 objet to a Player variable.

Comment: Maybe there's several errors, and the bad symbol is actually `a` and `b` due to cascading failures...

Answer (score 2):

Probably the unshown base class or interface `Player` doesn't specify a method `setBoard()`.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Player a = new Player_p2();
```

To

```
Player_p2 a = new Player_p2()
```

Answer (score 1):

simply change Player to Player_p2